# Why does the slideOutLeft CSS not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple tab with the jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` but I have a problem the `slideOutLeft` not working: slide out left doesn't work after clicking twice. What am I missing here and can anyone can help me in this regard?

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/wGRpBE)** in codepen.io:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tabContainer">
      <div class="tabItem" id="1">1</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="2">2</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="3">3</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="4">4</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="5">5</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="6">6</div>
      <div class="tabItem" id="7">7</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabBody">
      <div class="tabMain active" id="tab1">1</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab2">2</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab3">3</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab4">4</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab5">5</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab6">6</div>
      <div class="tabMain leftRight" id="tab7">7</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:550px;
   margin:0px auto;
   background-color:#d8dbdf;
   overflow:hidden;
   border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-border-radius:2px;
}
.tabContainer {
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#009688;
    border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-border-radius:2px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.tabBody {
   position:relative;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   height:300px;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
.tabItem {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   padding: 5px 8px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   color:#ffffff;
   width:14%;
}
.tabMain {
   width:100%;
   min-height:300px;
   background-color:#f8f8f8;
   transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
   opacity:0;
  display:none;
}
.active {
  opacity:1;
   display:block;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
-moz-animation: slideInRight 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation: slideInRight 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  animation: slideInRight 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;

}
.leftRight{
   opacity:0;
   display:none;
  -moz-animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}

@keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}

.slideOutLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideOutLeft;
  animation-name: slideOutLeft
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    visibility: visible
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    visibility: visible
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.slideInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-name: slideInRight
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".tabItem", function() {
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".tabMain").removeClass("active").addClass("leftRight");

      $("#tab" + ID).addClass("active").removeClass("leftRight");;
   });

});
```

Comment: I think  the  problem  is opacity and display.  You  need to check  that.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Pugazh How could I be more specific this is a specific question i think.

Comment: @DevStud You say, in your comment under my answer: 'I want it to slide out after clicking twice.' Thank you for now adding this information, as asked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the sliding animation is tied to the the `leftRight` class; this class is removed when the tab is active, so clicking again doesn't trigger the animation. You'll need to trigger the animation again when clicking on an active tab, either by adding the `leftRight` class again or by moving the animation to another class.

Chrome is really useful for debugging animations - you can see the animations triggered on each class by opening the 'Animations' tab in the top-right of the devtools (the double-diamond icon):

[image]